# Why do I have to initialise variable?

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, boolean

My code is checking if a given string is in a certain format. The first char of the string has to be an uppercase letter and the rest of the string has to be any number that is from 1 to given dimension.

If the first char of the string contains a string from the alphabet array, then the code checks if the rest of the string contains a number from the numbers array. To be a valid coordinate both conditions must be true, if one of them is false it is not a valid coordinate. I want to return the boolean isValidCoordinate but however IntelliJ is telling me that I have to initialise isValid coordinate. Why do I have to initialise it, the boolean expression depends on the 'if' conditions.

Thanks.

```
public static boolean validCoordinate(String coordinate, int dimension) {
        boolean isValidCoordinate;
        String [] alphabet = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
        int [] numbers = new int [dimension];
        int one = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++){
            numbers[i] = one + i;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++){
            if((Character.toString(coordinate.charAt(0))).contains(alphabet[i])) {
                for(int j = 0; j < dimension; j++) {
                    if ((coordinate.substring(1)).contains(Integer.toString(numbers[j]))) {
                        isValidCoordinate = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        isValidCoordinate = false;
                    }
                }

            }
            else {
                isValidCoordinate = false;
            }

        }

        return isValidCoordinate;
    }
```

This is my final code:

```
public static boolean validCoordinate(String coordinate, int dimension) {
        boolean isValidCoordinate;
        String [] alphabet = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
        int [] numbers = new int [dimension];
        int one = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++){
            numbers[i] = one + i;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++){
            if((Character.toString(coordinate.charAt(0))).contains(alphabet[i])) {
                for(int j = 0; j < dimension; j++) {
                    if ((coordinate.substring(1)).contains(Integer.toString(numbers[j]))) {
                        isValidCoordinate = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        isValidCoordinate = false;
                    }
                }

            }
            else {
                isValidCoordinate = false;
            }

        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Because in your case it could happen that your boolean never get any value asigned. Just initialize it with "boolean isValiedCoordinate = false" and you are good to go.

Comment: Why make an array that hold all alphabet characters? Use Regex OR depend on the ASCII code of each character

Comment: I do not know how to do regex, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

All the cases inside the `for` loop are covered, but not the case when `dimension` is 0.

The method will go straight to `return isValidCoordinate;`, where the variable isn't initialized yet.

Comment: dimension is not a List.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that your for loop will never be entered (for example, if `dimension == 0`). In that case, you will never assign a value to `isValidCoordinate`, but you will attempt to return the value of that variable in the last statement of your method.

What would be the value of `isValidCoordinate` in such case?

It wouldn't have any value.

Therefore, you are forced by the compiler to assign an initial value to `isValidCoordinate`, to make sure that it has a value before it is accessed.

EDIT:

Following your comments, I suggest you eliminate the `boolean` variable, and use return statements instead:

```
public static boolean validCoordinate(String coordinate, int dimension) {
    String [] alphabet = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
    int [] numbers = new int [dimension];
    int one = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++){
        numbers[i] = one + i;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++){
        if((Character.toString(coordinate.charAt(0))).contains(alphabet[i])) {
            for(int j = 0; j < dimension; j++) {
                if ((coordinate.substring(1)).contains(Integer.toString(numbers[j]))) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

This way you don't have to worry about breaking out of nested loops when the `boolean` variable is set to `true`.

Comment: Even tho I initialised isValidCoordinate both true and false, the output is only false. "A1 5" is giving me false so does "hjsu 10".

Comment: @KaleJoe that's a different issue. I'm not sure what's the exact logic, but perhaps you want to break out of the loop after `isValidCoordinate = true;`. Otherwise you might set it back to false in the next iteration.

Comment: @KaleJoe In that case, either put a `break;` statement, or replace `isValidCoordinate = true` with `return true;` You can even get rid of the boolean variable.

Comment: I tried putting break after isValidCoordinate = true; in the loop but still got false.

Comment: @KaleJoe Well, I just noticed that you have nested loops. break will only break out of the inner loop, so it's not enough. Perhaps you should just return true instead of assigning true to the variable.

Comment: True, changed my code adding my final code to my question, thanks hope it works now!

Comment: @KaleJoe you have 2 loops. If you break out of the inner loop (over j), you'd still be inside the outer loop (over i). See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public static boolean validCoordinate(String coordinate, int dimension)
{
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(coordinate);
    return m.matches();
}
```

Comment: Although this might accomplish the OP's programming objective, it in no way addresses the question they posed.

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.